# Call to IVR from Polycom IP 7000

Tags: voip

Есть *CUCM 6.0* и телефон *Polycom ip 7000*. Телефон зарегистрировался, обычные звонки работают.

Проблема заключается в следующем. При звонке на *IVR*, и вступительного сообщения можно набрать добавочный номер, но при его наборе нет гудков, просто тишина. При этом, звонок проходит и если абонент поднял трубку, связь установится и можно будет общаться.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Напишите вопрос на русском языке иначе его закроют.

Comment: Думаю, нужно копать в сторону ringback настроек, второй пост https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11044596/no-ringback-calling-cucm-h323-gw